# Stop Isotope running initial animation on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Even though all the documentation says that Isotope should not run animation on page load, my page seems to do it every time.

It's set to use CSS as the animation engine, so I can't see a way to disable it or change the duration at run-time.

I am running the code using the copy & pasted code from the Isotope demo (albeit with slightly modified class names), but still no joy. See code snippet below:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // Isotope Filtering
    var $container = $('#portfolioItems');
    $container.isotope({
        // options...
    });

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('.filter_nav a').click(function ()
    {
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

        return false;
    });

});
```

The actual filtering is working fine, just want to prevent the initial animation.

Thanks!!

Comment: It always seems to do the initial animation from the start positions (0,0) to their resting places. Have you tried setting the `animationOptions: Duration` to a very small number initially so it happens instantly?

Comment: @HiTechMagic - that's a great idea but I'm using CSS transitions rather than jQuery for the animation, so I don't think I can change it? Sorry should've mentioned that in my post. : )

Comment: Doesn't matter. The timing is used by the CSS transitions it generates on the items. Just change it initially and change it back in isotope's`onLayout` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of targeting `.isotope` for transitions in your css, target a new class - e.g. `.isotope-ready`

```
.isotope-ready, .isotope-ready .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
       -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
        -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
         -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
            transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope-ready {
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
       -moz-transition-property: height, width;
        -ms-transition-property: height, width;
         -o-transition-property: height, width;
            transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope-ready .isotope-item {
      -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
         -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
          -ms-transition-property:     -ms-transform, opacity;
           -o-transition-property:      -o-transform, opacity;
              transition-property:         transform, opacity;
}
```

Compass version below :

```
.isotope-ready, .isotope-ready .isotope-item
    +transition-duration(.8s)
.isotope-ready
    +transition-property(height, width)
    .isotope-item
        +transition-property(transform, opacity)
```

Then add your new class in isotope’s onLayout callback

```
onLayout: function() {
   $('.isotope').addClass('isotope-ready');
}
```